# What is the meaning of this error: "Problem accessing file status"?

Tags: command-line, c

I am compiling in terminal a c code and when I am trying to run it I got this error.
Is there any specific meaning?
and how I can fix it?

Comment: Post the exact command you used and the exact error you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need some special (root) permission to compile a code. In Linux most of the time you need to be **root** when doing some special task, such as changing permission(s) of the system file, changing owner of the file, and to copy, move or remove any file from the Linux system directories located inside root path (/) etc.

So you need root permissions to compile your code as,

```
sudo gcc -o Output Hello.c 

or

sudo g++ -o Output Hello.c
```

*After executing above command you need to enter your **root password**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access that file using terminal.
See if you are facing any problem by it.

Once you are done with it, then proceed with the c program.
May be you are trying to access a file for which you need root permission.

So, either you can use this commmand on a file

```
sudo chown USERNAME FILENAME
```

It will change the ownership of the file from root to USERNAME.

or you can also use sudo to compile and run the program with sudo privilege

```
sudo gcc -o Output Hello.c
```

also, there is another way around. You can use these commands to get your work done..

```
sudo chown root:USERNAME Output  
sudo chmod 4550 Output        // use SUID to get root privilege
```